# Can not use /bin/zsh to compile a csharp program, but /bin/bash can

Tags: c#, bash, mono, zsh, gmcs

My env

```
OSX 10.11.6
zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Mono C# compiler version 4.0.5.0
```

test.cs

```
class Test {
        public static void Main() {
                System.Console.WriteLine("hello, world");
        }
}
```

test.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

mcs -recurse:*.cs
```

I can use ./test.sh to compile test.cs

but if I change test.sh to

```
#! /bin/zsh

mcs -recurse:*.cs
```

error shows

```
./test.sh:3: no matches found: -recurse:*.cs
```

So, Why I can not use zsh?

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` is attempting to expand the `*` in that word as a file glob, failing, and throwing an error.

`bash` does the same thing but, by default, it just ignores the globbing failure and keeps the word intact (so `mcs` sees the argument it expects).

Add `shopt -s failglob` to the top of the script (for `bash`) and it will fail also.

Quote the `*` in the argument to `mcs` to avoid this.

```
mcs -recurse:'*.cs'
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the string `-recurse:*.cs` contains an unquoted `*`, most shells will attempt to treat it as a glob pattern and expand it to one or more matching file names.

The default behavior in `zsh` is to treat a pattern that has no matches as an error, rather than treating the pattern as a literal string. The same behavior can be seen in `bash` if you enable the `failglob` option.

```
$ echo foo*
foo*
$ shopt -s failglob
$ echo foo*
bash: no match: foo*
```

In `zsh`, either quote the pattern:

```
#! /bin/zsh

mcs -recurse:"*.cs"
```

turn off the `NOMATCH` option,

```
#! /bin/zsh

setopt NO_NOMATCH
mcs -recurse:*.cs
```

or use the zsh command modifier:

```
#! /bin/zsh

noglob mcs -recurse:*.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

In your command `mcs -recurse:*.cs`, the `*` is intended to be passed to `mcs` as a literal part of the argument, but it is also meaningful to all common Unix shells (`bash`, `zsh`, `tcsh`, and others) as a wildcard for pathname expansion.  As such, your command would probably surprise you if there were a file named `-recurse:oops.cs` in the working directory.

The difference arises in the shells' default behavior when no file matches the given pattern.  By default, `bash` falls back to guessing that you meant the `*` to be a literal, which is in fact what you meant.  `zsh`, on the other hand, exhibits the more traditional behavior of failing on account of the failure to match the pattern.  `bash` can be induced to exhibit that behavior, too, by turning on its `failglob` option.

The best solution is to resolve the ambiguity by quoting the argument, or at least escaping the `*` in it.  Both `bash` and `zsh` should handle this version fine without any special options:

```
mcs -recurse:\*.cs
```